Too many re-renders while calling api for each item inside map function
When I map the order_item array, It checks for a condition and in else block there's an api call through fetchData function which runs on each item of order item. It should technically stop after map items are finished but it just keeps running in infinite loop.
  item.order_item.map((item2, index) => {
    if (!item2.order_meal_deliveries.length > 0) {
      return (
        <div className="col-12 card card-md mb-4" key={index}>
          <div className="col-auto">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg">
                <div className="col-12 p-4">
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="row align-items-center">
                      <div className="col">
                        <div className="tag mb-2">
                          {item2.plan_type === 1 ? "Wellness" : "Individual"}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-auto">
                        <p className="mb-0 text-grey">
                          <span className="fw-bold">Order ID:</span> MUSF00
                          {item.id}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h5 className="fw-semibold ">
                    {item2.item_details.product_title}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span className="fw-regular text-grey"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  </h5>
                  <p className="text-grey mb-4">
                    Durations: {item2.subscription_days} day
                  </p>
                  <h6 className="mb-1">Plan duration</h6>
                  <p className="text-grey">
                    Not Started of {item2.subscription_days} Days
                  </p>
                  <div className="progress">
                    <div
                      className="progress-bar"
                      role="progressbar"
                      aria-valuemax="100"
                      style={{ width: "0%" }}
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div className="col-lg-5 border-start d-flex align-items-center">
                <div className="col-12 p-4 text-center  ">
                  <div className="col-12 form-group ">
                    <h6 className="mb-1 fw-medium text-start">
                      Start your plan
                    </h6>
                    <DatePicker
                      selected={startDate}
                      onChange={(date) => {
                        setStartDate(date);
                      }}
                      minDate={minDate}
                      className="form-control col-12"
                      dateFormat={"dd/MM/yyyy"}
                    />
                  </div>
                  {/* <div className="col-12 form-group">
                                                                                <h6 className="mb-1 fw-medium">End date</h6>
                                                                                <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Select date" />
                                                                            </div> */}
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={() =>
                      createMealDelivery(item.id, item2.id, item2.plan_type)
                    }
                  >
                    Start meal plan
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    } else {
      fetchData(item.id, item2.id);

      return (
        <div className="col-12 card card-md mb-4" key={index}>
          <div className="col-auto">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg">
                <div className="col-12 p-4">
                  <div className="col-12">
                    <div className="row align-items-center">
                      <div className="col">
                        <div className="tag mb-2">
                          {item2.plan_type === 1 ? "Wellness" : "Individual"}
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-auto">
                        <p className="mb-0 text-grey">
                          <span className="fw-bold">Order ID:</span> MUSF00
                          {item.id}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <h5 className="fw-semibold ">
                    {item2.item_details.product_title}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <span className="fw-regular text-grey"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                  </h5>
                  <p className="text-grey mb-4">
                    Durations: {item2.subscription_days} day
                  </p>
                  <h6 className="mb-1">Plan duration</h6>
                  <p className="text-grey">
                    Not Started of {item2.subscription_days} Days
                  </p>
                  <div className="progress">
                    <div
                      className="progress-bar"
                      role="progressbar"
                      aria-valuemax="100"
                      style={{ width: setProgressBarValue() }}
                    ></div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-12 pt-4 mt-4 border-top">
                    <div className="row justify-content-between">
                      <div className="col-auto">
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                          onClick={() => handleViewMeal(item2.id, item.id)}
                        >
                          View plan
                        </button>
                      </div>
                      <div className="col-auto">
                        <button
                          className="btn btn-primary"
                          onClick={() => handleRenewPlan(item2)}
                        >
                          Renew plan
                        </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }),
);

const fetchData = (orderId, itemId) => {
  api
    .ordersDelivery(orderId, itemId)

    .then((res) => {
      //    console.log(res?.data?.response?.pending_delivery_count)
      setPendingDeliveries(res?.data?.response?.pending_delivery_count);
      //    console.log(res?.data?.response?.total_delivery_count)
      setTotalDeliveries(res?.data?.response?.total_delivery_count);
    })

    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

I know the reason of this behaviour, the setting of state in map function is causing it to re render the component.
Each item should have its own value of pending delivery and total delivery , which is taken from api response how do I achieve that

I didn't understood why you have to fetchData(item.id, item2.id) it seems to be the wrong place to do it. It is missing some information to answer

I think what you are trying to do is call your Api if item2 has no order_meal_deliveries?
I think the easiest way to do this would be create a new component for the map function.
The new Item component
    export const Item = (item2, itemId) => {
  const [pendingDeliveriesCount, setPendingDeliveriesCount] = useState();
  const [totalDeliveriesCount, setTotalDeliveriesCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
   if(item2.order_meal_deliveries.length === 0){
    api.ordersDelivery(orderId, item2.id)
    .then(res => {
    //    console.log(res?.data?.response?.pending_delivery_count)
    setPendingDeliveriesCount(res?.data?.response?.pending_delivery_count);
    //    console.log(res?.data?.response?.total_delivery_count)
    setTotalDeliveriesCount(res?.data?.response?.total_delivery_count);
    })

    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
   }
  }, [item2, itemId]);

  return (
    <div className="col-12 card card-md mb-4" key={index}>
      <div className="col-auto">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-lg">
            <div className="col-12 p-4">
              <div className="col-12">
                <div className="row align-items-center">
                  <div className="col">
                    <div className="tag mb-2">
                      {item2.plan_type === 1 ? "Wellness" : "Individual"}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-auto">
                    <p className="mb-0 text-grey">
                      <span className="fw-bold">Order ID:</span> MUSF00{item.id}
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <h5 className="fw-semibold ">
                {item2.item_details.product_title}&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <span className="fw-regular text-grey"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;
              </h5>
              <p className="text-grey mb-4">
                Durations: {item2.subscription_days} day
              </p>
              <h6 className="mb-1">Plan duration</h6>
              <p className="text-grey">
                Not Started of {item2.subscription_days} Days
              </p>
              <div className="progress">
                <div
                  className="progress-bar"
                  role="progressbar"
                  aria-valuemax="100"
                  style={{ width: "0%" }}
                ></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          {!item2.order_meal_deliveries.length > 0 ? (
            <div className="col-lg-5 border-start d-flex align-items-center">
              <div className="col-12 p-4 text-center  ">
                <div className="col-12 form-group ">
                  <h6 className="mb-1 fw-medium text-start">Start your plan</h6>
                  <DatePicker
                    selected={startDate}
                    onChange={(date) => {
                      setStartDate(date);
                    }}
                    minDate={minDate}
                    className="form-control col-12"
                    dateFormat={"dd/MM/yyyy"}
                  />
                </div>
                {/* <div className="col-12 form-group">
                      <h6 className="mb-1 fw-medium">End date</h6>
                      <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Select date" />
                  </div> */}
                <button
                  className="btn btn-primary"
                  onClick={() =>
                    createMealDelivery(item.id, item2.id, item2.plan_type)
                  }
                >
                  Start meal plan
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <div className="col-12 pt-4 mt-4 border-top">
              <div className="row justify-content-between">
                <div className="col-auto">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-outline-primary"
                    onClick={() => handleViewMeal(item2.id, item.id)}
                  >
                    View plan
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div className="col-auto">
                  <button
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    onClick={() => handleRenewPlan(item2)}
                  >
                    Renew plan
                  </button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

The revised map function
  mealPlans.map((item, mealIndex) =>
  item.order_item.map((item2, index) => {        
      return <Item item2={item2} itemId={itemId}></Item>;        
  })
);

